# How to get JSON data in a variable?

Tags: php, json, variables

I'm working with the YouTube analytics API and Google OAuth and everything is working great. What I need is the amount of views in a variable. This is the JSON code:

```
{ "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
  "columnHeaders": [ { "name": "views",
                       "columnType": "METRIC",
                       "dataType": "INTEGER" } ],
   "rows": [ [ 8242.0 ] ] }
```

How do I get the value 8242.0 in a variable? I tried this:

```
$json = file_get_contents("url");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$views = $data['youtubeAnalytics#resultTable']['views'];
```

Also tried:

```
$views = $data['kind']['views'];
```

I can't get it working. Can someone help me?

Comment: `print_r($data)` will show you the format of the data in PHP terms. It shouldn't be difficult from that point on.

Comment: For this particular case, you need `$data['rows'][0][0]`

Comment: `echo '<pre>';var_dump($data);die;`

Comment: **Yawn...** basic debugging... https://eval.in/95162

Comment: OK, so it's a really bad question. But here's the thing: that downvote button that reads "not useful"? It means not useful *for answering the question*, not "not useful according to my own arbitrary standards of usefulness". Why you would choose to punish people who are trying to help (even if you find their methods not to your taste) is completely beyond me. Thanks for listening, PHP chatroom gang.

Comment: I agree with @Jon, three downvotes apiece for both answers here seems a bit harsh. They're rather brief for my taste, but nevertheless I've upvoted both to even things out a bit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
    $views = $data['rows'][0][0];
```

a simple print_r() will show you the $data array, in this case the json is pretty simple, you check the first level commas, that's your array keys, then the [ [ ] ] suggest two nested arrays in the 'rows' key

Comment: Works! Thank you. can you explain it?

Comment: a simple `print_r` will show you the $data array, in this case the json is pretty simple, you check the first level commas, that's your array keys, then the [ [ ] ] suggest two nested arrays

Answer (score -1):

Well, it is `$data['rows'][0][0]`. See, when you don't know what output did you get out of a function, you can always check the contents like this:

```
print_r($data);
```